# Run multiple video file in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video

There are two video file.When I want to see these two video

1) Only the last video file can play,see in fullscreen mode and also  minimise when done button clicked..but first video file can't .

2) After a few time the first video file also see in black screen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
    NSArray *filename=@[@"nissan1",@"nissan5"];
    //n![enter image description here][1]issan1,nissan5 are mp4 file
    NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                      pathForResource:[filename objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"mp4"]];

            moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL1];
            [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 100,100)];
            moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
            moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
            moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
            moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
            [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];




            /* second video file*/

           NSURL *fileURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                      pathForResource:[filename objectAtIndex:1] ofType:@"mp4"]];
           moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL2];
           [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 50, 100,100)];
           moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
           moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
           moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
           moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
          [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
          [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }
```

Comment: You should retain the two MPMoviePlayerController instances by adding properties for them. Since the moviePlayer variable is declared locally within the viewDidLoad, ARC targets it for deallocation once the method ends.

Comment: see this [link]http://i58.tinypic.com/flfz2f.png

Answer (score 0):

You should try with two instances. As Cristik pointed out,  ARC targets it for deallocation once the method ends and you are using same variable.

Since you asked for sample code, try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer1;
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer2;

    //filename is a name array
    NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                      pathForResource:[filename objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"mp4"]];

            moviePlayer1= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL1];
            [moviePlayer1.view setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 100,100)];
            moviePlayer1.shouldAutoplay = NO;
            moviePlayer1.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
            moviePlayer1.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
            moviePlayer1.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
            [moviePlayer1 prepareToPlay];
            [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer1.view];




            /* second video file*/

           NSURL *fileURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                      pathForResource:[filename objectAtIndex:1] ofType:@"mp4"]];
           moviePlayer2= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL2];
           [moviePlayer2.view setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 50, 100,100)];
           moviePlayer2.shouldAutoplay = NO;
           moviePlayer2.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
           moviePlayer2.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
           moviePlayer2.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
          [moviePlayer2 prepareToPlay];
          [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer2.view];
    }
```

Comment: I also try it..but it doesn't work.The first video is completely black screen.
It also seen a error like <Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.

Comment: Then most  probably your video is not proper. Have you tried playing that video outside your app?

Comment: Hmm...two video is proper..when I take  only one video,then video is works. But in two video,first is run,but does not minimise when done button pressed..after some times it will get black screen.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying exactly. Does first video plays outside your app or not? Or just try with some other videos.

Comment: two video plays outside my app..but previous comment is for inside event of app.